# Optimize Code into 'return' line?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to tighten this up so that there is only 1 line in the body?

```
private int _ProjectGuidToId (Guid guid)
{
    ProjectEntity res = _dbt.ProjectEntity
                            .Where(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString())
                            .First();
    return res.Id;
}
```

In other words, how do I return 1 value (Id) from 1 row from the database using LINQ in one line of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the newlines, perhaps?

Comment: Isn't that already doing it? Or do you want `return _dbt.ProjectEntity.Where(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString()).First().Id`?

Comment: Why are you doing `guid.ToString()`? is `ProjectedGUID` not a `Guid`? if not, then it's a rather badly named property...

Comment: @TrevorPilley in the database, it is a string.

Comment: @Eric in that case, I'd suggest you either change the property name or the column to a uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private int _ProjectGuidToId (Guid guid)
{
    return _dbt.ProjectEntity.First(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString()).Id;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thank you much! :)

Comment: You don't need the where clause. See my answer.

Comment: Actually, I forgot that `.First` can take a predicate as well. @MetroSmurf I ninja'd your answer already :-)

Comment: Stealthy. From here on out, you shall be known as PlatinumNinjaSmurf.

Comment: Excellent. I am duly honored. (Thank you for reminding me of the `.First` overload which takes a predicate.)

Answer (score 2):

The where clause can be eliminated by using the First's predicate clause:

```
return _dbt.ProjectEntity.First( r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString() ).Id;
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for helping a newbie out with 'tricks' like these. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the .Id to the end of the first line and return the single line.

I would, however, discourage this.  A single unreadable line is in my opinion worse code than two readable lines.

Comment: Thank you for the caution. I am new, for sure, and appreciate any input.

Comment: My view is that unless it is really causing major problems with speed then make your code as readable as possible.  If later on it comes to a point where your code really does need to be highly optimized either for source code size or speed for example, then look into doing things like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first will return the type of the object and no casting is needed ([More Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx).

Just do this line:

```
 return _dbt.ProjectEntity.Where(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString()).First().Id;
```

NOTE: If the query is not guaranteed to return one object an InvalidOperationException  could be thrown!

Comment: Thank you for the note. I am guaranteed that the GUID will be in the DB. :)

Comment: You are thinking of `Single()`, you would get an `InvalidOperationException` stating that the sequence contains no elements if there are no matches, however if there are multiple, you will get the `First`.

Comment: Actually, it will throw a different exception corresponding to no instance being found. `.FirstOrDefault` is exception-free but returns null, leading to a `NullReferenceException` when accessing the `.Id` property.

Comment: No, the example is calling `.First()` which will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if there are none http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx - see the exceptions table.

Comment: @TrevorPilley thanks I was thinking FirstOrDefault in my head.

Answer (score -1):

use this if you want to force the list must contains one item. if list contains more than one item error may raised:

```
return _dbt.ProjectEntity.Single(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString()).Id;
```

and use this if not matter the length of the list:

```
return _dbt.ProjectEntity.First(r => r.ProjectGUID == guid.ToString()).Id;
```